# Implementing social post visibility in web app

Tags: mongodb, join, meteor, social-networking, nosql

I want to implement a social network posting feature with post, comment, and set post visibility features in my application.

I am using Meteor platform. Put aside for a while the fact that relational databases are more suited to social network related data. I will use relational documents in separate collections for storing posts and comments and their meta data like poster or commented, with references. So, for reading, I will simulate sql-like joins with one of the meteor packages supports this in server side publish.

But I am not certain how I will implement post visibility setting in order to make a post visible to people that a poster wants the post be visible to, and invisible to people a poster wants them not to see. Visibility presets are "only me", "friends", "friends of friends", "groups", and individual specific groups that the user is a member of, and "public".

So far my collections are "users", "friends", "memberships" (referring to groups)", "posts", "comments", "likes". I can publish a reactive join of a desired combination of the posts, comments, likes, users by say [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite), package.

What is the preferred way of implementing this behaviour in the publish level? Or it is not a good idea at publish level, just try a conditional (iffy) publish.

Comment: real-world social networks build specialized databases for this kind of stuff. It's a tough problem

Comment: And you have chosen probably the worst database for this type of app. It's arguable whether social graph is relational data or not, but it most certainly is not meant to be stored in a document database.

Comment: while posts and users, friendships and memberships are separate collections, one way seems at first is to save the friends and memeberships of a user in its doc in users collection and do the same for the visibility property in the doc for a post in posts collection. and then range check with operator $in. Is that a good approach?

Comment: No, it's a terrible idea. Imagine that a user has 1000 friends. And he adds another one. Now you have to update all 1001 friends (if we still want "friends of friends")

Comment: What is this case? there is not a case in which it is necessity to update all 1001 friends when user with 1000 friends adds another one.

Comment: You want friends of friends, don't you?

Comment: So, user A (with 1000 friends) added user B. Now you have to update all 1000 initial friends to push user B to their friends-of-friends lists. Also you want to push these 1000 friends to B's friends-of-friends. See?

Comment: A Reference design was published some time ago: https://github.com/10gen-labs/socialite. It's a Java Service design, but it is an example. You can also search on the terms and find various presentation examples.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: thanks for the link, haven't seen this one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's some nice work by Daren mostly, who has spent some time working with "graph" databases and therefore adapting the concepts to a MongoDB reference.